# Adding a parameter to callback function inside of callback function

Tags: javascript, jquery

This might have been asked before, but I can't find any good examples on how to accomplish this.

I have a callback which is fired. But inside this callback i need to add a new parameter to the ending callback function. How can I do this:

```
var form_to_submit = function() {    
   var parameters = {
       param1 : "1",
       param2 : "2"  
   }
   // do_something with the parameters
}

first_function(form_to_submit);

function first_function(form_to_submit) {
   if($.isFunction(form_to_submit)) {
       var token = "new parameter"; // this parameter should be added to parameters in form_to_submit()
       form_to_submit(); // need to pass on the token to this function call
   }
}
```

Comment: Why can't you just pass the parameter?  This question is not very clear.

Comment: Updated, the question, to clarify

Comment: Still makes no sense.  Why are you declaring "parameters" like that?  If you want the function to take parameters, you should declare it with parameters.

Comment: The parameters in form_to_submit is set within this function for a reason, the new parameter in first_function is added after some security checks have been made. My example is a stripped down version of the entire code, but the logic is the same.

Answer (score 2):

```
if($.isFunction(form_to_submit)) {
   var token = data['token'];
   form_to_submit(token); // need to pass on the token to this function call
} else {
   form_to_submit.submit();
}
```

I think the syntax you are looking for is that of the above.  You don't need to modify the `if($.isFunction(form_to_submit))` line because all you're telling it is to use that function.  At that point it doesn't care about parameters.